# How to increase memory for scheduled 2nd generation Google Cloud function without using setGlobalOptions()?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am using Google Firebase in my project and I started using 2nd generation of Google Cloud functions recently and there is a function that uses scheduler which will invoke the function every 5 minutes.  I would like to know how to increase the memory for this function.  I don't want to use "setGlobalOptions({)" because that will apply to all functions.  Is there a way to accomplish that only for this function.  Here is how the function looks like:

```
// const { setGlobalOptions } = require('firebase-functions/v2');
const { onSchedule } = require('firebase-functions/v2/scheduler');


// I don't want this option since it applies to all functions
// setGlobalOptions({ memory:"512MiB" });

// there is no way to add options to onSchedule()??
exports.myFunction = onSchedule(
  '*/5 * * * *',
  async (context) => {
    // code goes here
  }
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass an [**ScheduleOptions**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.scheduler.scheduleoptions.md#schedulerscheduleoptions_interface) object as the first parameter, which is basically an extension of [**GlobalOptions**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptions_interface) to use these options per function basis so you can set the memory per function as follows :

```js
import {
    onSchedule
} from "firebase-functions/v2/scheduler";
export const myScheduleFunction = onSchedule({
        memory: "512MiB",
        timeoutSeconds: 60,
        schedule: "*/5 * * * *",
        // include other options here from SchedulerOptions or GlobalOptions
    },
    async (context) => {
        // code goes here
    }
);
```

Reference : [**scheduler.onSchedule()**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.scheduler.md#scheduleronschedule_2)

Comment: This is strange.  When I checked the docs, they said the first parameter is a string for the schedule time.  They never said anything about option object?? Maybe I was looking at older version!!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Aimn Blbol Yeah there are 2 variants of that function one with `ScheduleOptions` using this will have to mention the cron string inside the `ScheduleOptions` object and another variant is without `ScheduleOptions` in which we define cron string as 1st argument.